# grouping CSS elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having a real hard time wrapping my brain around grouping different selectors and styles into one coherent setup.

I found this one set of CSS/HTML code that is exactly what I need (http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/daFDn/) but I'm at a loss how I can utilize it with my setup.

```
    body {
    padding: 50px;
}
ul {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 301px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
li {
    font: bold 16px/100px sans-serif;
    height: 100px;
}
a {
    border-right: 1px solid #444;
    border-top: 1px solid #444;
    color: red;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 99px;
}
li:first-child a {
    border-top: none;
}
li:nth-child(2) a {
    color: blue;
}
li:nth-child(3) a {
    color: green;
}
a:hover {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
}
img {
    background: red;
    display: none;
    height: 301px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
li:nth-child(2) img {
    background: blue;
}
li:nth-child(3) img {
    background: green;
}
a:hover + img,
img:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

I have a WordPress site, using Headway Themes (GUI theme creator).  I want to create a section on one page that does exactly what the Fiddle does.  I also don't want any other similar HTML elements to be affected by the CSS in that fiddle. (i.e. I use LI's elsewhere on the site and don't want them "font: bold 16px/100px sans-serif;" like this example).

For me, this truly baffles my mind and would seriously appreciate some guidance on how to structure this correctly.

I'm sure I need to create an ID (because this page will be unique to the rest of the site) but I'm not sure that this is correct syntax for an ID:

```
#switch  ul {border: 1px solid #444;display: inline-block;height: 301px;  position: relative;width: 400px;}, li {font: bold 16px/100px sans-serif;height: 100px;}
```

(as an example but is essentially what I want to do)

Answer (score 1):

Just had a quick stab at this - As you say, you'll need to add something to limit those selectors to the scope you're interested in. An id is one way of doing this - in that case you would need to update your selectors to look something like: http://jsfiddle.net/2osg7a31/

Two things to look out for:
 - `ul#switch` instead of `#switch ul` (since you're applying the styles to the `ul` that has an id of `#switch`, rather than a `ul` with a descendant of `#switch`)
 - Make sure all styles for the descendants are limited to the `#switch` id too,  not just those applied directly to the `ul` tag.

I'd suggest using a class instead of an id might be a better idea, since you're only adding the identifier to allow styling, rather than to try and identify the element uniquely: http://jsfiddle.net/0h54wseL/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to use and id or preferably a **class** which is better if you want to repeat that specific fiddle in other pages of your website. The way to do it is to add a `.switch` in every css entry for the list style. Then in your HTML put the whole `ul` inside a `div` with `class="switch"`.

HTML:

```
<div class="switch">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <img src="" alt=""/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <img src="" alt=""/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <img src="" alt=""/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle to explain : http://jsfiddle.net/zyd1822w/1/

Also check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more info about essential css selectors.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome!  I knew I was close but just needed that example to help me understand!  Thanks tons!